# How to remove github-pages from Environments in GitHub repository?

Tags: git, github, version-control, github-pages, environment

I have created a project page for a repository in GitHub and later I deleted the **gh-pages** branch to delete the page. But now I see **github-pages** **Active** under the **Environments** section in the home page of my repository.

[image]

I have no idea what that section is and how to remove it. When I click on the **Environments**, I am taken to the page with following; **View deployment** button takes me to a broken 404 github page since I have deleted the page I created.
[image]

Answer (score 18):

Check in Settings>Environments
Or https://github.com/user/repo-name/settings/environments

Where "user" should be your username and "repo-name" the repo name

It will show a icon to delete github-pages

Answer (score 6):

If you are using Chrome then try to clear browsing data for the last 24 hours and restart. This worked for me.

(*Forced to post this as an answer instead of a comment due to lacking reputation points*)

Comment: also might be worthwhile trying the ctrl-f5 trick to force a "reload not from cache" on the page

Answer (score 1):

You can either hide it (if it's enough) by excluding it from the homepage by clicking on the cog icon above the environments, next to About and unchecking Environments (and all else you do not want there)

[image]

Or you can completly remove github pages by [following steps here](https://docs.github.com/en/github/working-with-github-pages/unpublishing-a-github-pages-site)

Comment: I have already deleted GitHub page by deleting gh-pages branch. It's also reflected under 'GitHub Pages' of settings as it's now showing 'None' under 'Source'. But still the Environments has the github-pages as Active and view deployment button leads to a 404 page.

Comment: I have also the same problem and solution proposed by [dylan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66004797/9475509) works for me.